# MODx - How to create MIGX inside another MIGX?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks, migx

Good day!
To my regret I can not create migx inside another migx.
Below is the code that I use.
mainTV (slider):

```
[
{"caption":"Info", "fields": [
    {"field":"slider_title","caption":"Header row","inputTV":"slider_title_row"},
    {"field":"image","caption":"Image","inputTV":"image_helper"}
]}
]
```

subTV (slider_title_row):

```
[
   {"caption":"Header row", "fields": [
    {"field":"title_row","caption":"Header row","inputTVtype":"text"}
   ]}
]
```

main call:

```
<div class="main-carousel">
    [[!getImageList? &tvname=`slider` &tpl=`Slider_title.tpl`]]
</div>
```

chank Slider_title.tpl:

```
<div class="main-carousel__item carousel-item" style="background-image:url([[+image]]);">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-item__description">
      <h2>[[!getImageList?
            &tpl=`Slider_title_row.tpl`
            &value=`[[+slider_title]]`
           ]]
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

chank Slider_title_row.tpl:

```
<div>[[+title_row]]</div>
```

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the issue seems to be from the use of `&tvname` on the outer migx call.

Swap this to be similar to what you have for the inner one, and it should work just fine.

```
<div class="main-carousel">
    [[!getImageList? &value=`[[*slider]]` &tpl=`Slider_title.tpl`]]
</div>
```